# RSpec undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Having a weird error in spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb: undefined local variable or method 'profile'

Pasted in relevant sections of the controller:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factory_girl'

describe ProfilesController, :type => :controller do
  login_user #this is defined elsewhere, not an issue
  describe "PUT update" do
    before(:each) do
      @profile = FactoryGirl.create(:profile)
    end
    context "valid attributes" do
      it "located the requested @profile" do
        put :update, id: @profile, profile: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:profile)
        assigns(:profile).should eq(@profile)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the backtrace?  "undefined local variable or method xyz" is a general ruby error when you have a bare word that doesn't reference a defined local variable or method. You don't have any such `profile` bare word in the spec you posted above, so it's probably coming from something you are calling from this spec.

Comment: My profile factory: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/a5a46650a5a59bb4a69d

Comment: Backtrace: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/386b4f2a6b7438161096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there isn't a problem in your spec or your factory. The problem is with the controller you are testing.

The exception you see

```
1) ProfilesController PUT #update valid attributes located the requested @profile
   Failure/Error: put :update, id: @profile, profile: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:profile)
   NameError:
     undefined local variable or method `profile' for #<ProfilesController:0x007fae343cfe08>
```

tells you that your `ProfilesController` has undefined local variable or method `profile`.

In your controller, you have this line

```
if @profile.update(profile)
```

that most likely causes the error. Perhaps you need need to change that `update(profile)` to `update(profile_params)`? This is hard to tell without seeing the whole controller, but that would follow a common pattern. And I guess you have a method `profile_params` that returns the filtered params.

Comment: Here's my profile controller: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/66ea65a9390c9f25521d

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a factory in `test/factories.rb` or `spec/factories.rb`?

It'll look something like this:

```
# This will guess the User class
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
    admin false
  end

  # This will use the User class (Admin would have been guessed)
  factory :admin, class: User do
    first_name "Admin"
    last_name  "User"
    admin      true
  end
end
```

taken directly from the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! :)